# Is this differential equation logistic?

Tags: calculus

I have differential equation.

$$y'=-ay^2$$ where $a$ is a constant. My question is: is this logistic equation?

Comment: In what sence? If one takes [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html) definition, is not, as it implies zero rate of maximum population growth. Are you talking of abstract _logistic type_ equations, or in terms of logistic growth? Math and modeling are all about context.

Comment: I am talking in the sense that $y(t)= \frac{M}{1+ce^{-aMt}}$ where $c$  is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

If so, it's a degenerate one. But to my mind, only equations of the form $y'=ay-by^2$ with $a,b>0$ qualify as logistic. In a sense there is only one logistic equation, as a suitable rescaling always renders a logistic equation in its standard form $$y'=y-y^2.$$

Comment: I couldn't agree more. It's like calling $y'' = \frac{1}{y^2}$ the _degenerate gravitational equation_.

Answer (score 0):

One can determine that the solutions to this equation are $y=0$ and those of the form $y=\cfrac1{at+C}$ for some constant $C$. These aren't logistic.